# Jquery FadeIn() method happening twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

See the link below, what I'm trying to do is self explanatory... I'm switching between divs and having the current div fade out and a new one fading in. My problem is, if you try the example... Some times when I switch between "kitchen" and "electronics" I'm getting extra fadeIns and Fade Outs. Does anyone know I can fix this?

HTML:

```
            <div id="panelControllers">
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="1">
                    General
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="2">
                    Kitchen
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="3">
                    Electronics
                  </button>
                </li>
                    <li>
                  <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="4">
                    Outside
                  </button>
                </li>
                    <li>
                  <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="5">
                    Other
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="panelContainer">
            <div id="panel1" class="panel">
                <div class="row general">
                    <button data-value="8" value="4000" class="">Central Air Conditioner</button>
                    <button data-value="8" value="1000" class="">Room Air Conditioner</button>
                    <button data-value="8" value="300" class="">Portable Heater</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row general">
                    <button value="3" class="4900">Clothes Dryer</button>
                    <button value="3" class="512">Washer</button>
                    <button value="1" class="1000">Clothes Iron</button>
                    <button value="3" class="500">Upright Vacuum</button>
                    <button value="3" class="40">Hand Vacuum</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row general">
                    <button data-value="8" value="177" class="">Air Humidifier</button>
                    <button data-value="12" value="257" class="">Air Dehumidifier</button>
                    <button data-value="7" value="300" class="">Furnace Fan</button>
                    <button data-value="12" value="125" class="">Ceiling Fan</button>
                    <button data-value="2" value="1000" class="">Fan - Attic</button>
                    <button data-value="" value="300" class="">Fan - Furnace</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="panel2" class="panel" style="display:none;">
                <div class="row kitchen">
                    <button data-value="12" value="800">Large Refridgerator</button>
                    <button data-value="12" value="400">Small Refrigerator</button>
                    <button data-value="12" value="350">Freezer</button>
                    <button data-value="" value=""></button>
                </div>
                <div class="row kitchen">
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Oven</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="12200">Range</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Hot Plate</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1450">Microwave Oven</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1000">Microwave</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Toaster Oven</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Electric Frying Pan</button>
                    <button data-value="1" value="1200">DishWasher</button>
                    <button data-value="" value=""></button>
                </div>
                <div class="row kitchen">
                    <button data-value="1" value="900">Coffee Maker</button>
                    <button data-value="0.1" value="400">Blender/Food Processor</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="500">Blender</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Kettle</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row kitchen">
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="850">Toaster</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1500">Electric Grill</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Waffle Iron</button>
                    <button data-value="0.5" value="250">Rice Cooker</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="panel3" class="panel" style="display:none;">
                <div class="row electronics">
                    <button value="" value="">Small LED TV</button>
                    <button value="" value="">Large LED TV</button>
                    <button value="" value="">Small LCD TV</button>
                    <button value="" value="">Large LCD TV</button>
                    <button value="" value="40">VCR</button>

                    <button value="" value="30">CD Player</button>
                    <button value="" value=""></button>
                    <button value="" value=""></button>
                    <button value="" class=""></button>
                    <button value="" class=""></button>
                </div>
                <div class="row electronics">
                    <button value="" class="50">Laptop</button>
                    <button value="" class="300">Desktop Computer</button>
                    <button value="" value="100">Inkjet Printer</button>
                    <button value="" value="100">Lazer Printer</button>

                </div>
                <div class="row electronics">
                    <button value="" value="1">Electric Clock</button>
                    <button value="" value="1">Clock Radio</button>

                    <button value="" class="100">Radiotelephone</button>
                    <button value="" class="20">Stereo</button>

                </div>
                <div class="row electronics">
                    <button data-value="" value="12">Shaver</button>
                    <button data-value="" value="1000">Blow Dryer</button>

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
var currentPanel = 1;
$('.panelControlBtn').on("click", function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if (ID != currentPanel) {
    $(".panel").fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $("#panel" + ID).fadeIn('fast');
    });
currentPanel = ID;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L7cqnmma/

Comment: It's because you are doing to things, fadein and fadeout.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `$(".panel").fadeOut('fast'...` iterates through each `.panel` element. When you append `fadeIn` to this function, `fadeIn` happens more than once, which you don't want to happen. You have to apply `fadeIn` after fading out the last `.panel` element.

My suggested fix comes with the glorious `promise()`:

```
$('.panelControlBtn').on("click", function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if (ID != currentPanel) {
    $(".panel").fadeOut('fast').promise().done(function() { //Promise ensures that fadeOuts are finished before firing the upcoming action
      $("#panel" + ID).fadeIn('fast');
    });
    currentPanel = ID;
  }
});
```

A working snippet is below.

```js
var currentPanel = 1;

$('.panelControlBtn').on("click", function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if (ID != currentPanel) {
    $(".panel").fadeOut('fast').promise().done(function() { //Promise ensures that fadeOuts are finished before firing the upcoming action
      $("#panel" + ID).fadeIn('fast');
    });
    currentPanel = ID;
  }
});
```

```css
#panelControllers {
  height: 30px;
}

#panelControllers ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#panelContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panelControllers">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="1">
            General
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="2">
            Kitchen
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="3">
            Electronics
          </button>
        </li>
            <li>
          <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="4">
            Outside
          </button>
        </li>
            <li>
          <button class="panelControlBtn" data-id="5">
            Other
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="panelContainer">
    <div id="panel1" class="panel">
     <div class="row general">
      <button data-value="8" value="4000" class="">Central Air Conditioner</button>
      <button data-value="8" value="1000" class="">Room Air Conditioner</button>
      <button data-value="8" value="300" class="">Portable Heater</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row general">
      <button value="3" class="4900">Clothes Dryer</button>
      <button value="3" class="512">Washer</button>
      <button value="1" class="1000">Clothes Iron</button>
      <button value="3" class="500">Upright Vacuum</button>
      <button value="3" class="40">Hand Vacuum</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row general">
      <button data-value="8" value="177" class="">Air Humidifier</button>
      <button data-value="12" value="257" class="">Air Dehumidifier</button>
      <button data-value="7" value="300" class="">Furnace Fan</button>
      <button data-value="12" value="125" class="">Ceiling Fan</button>
      <button data-value="2" value="1000" class="">Fan - Attic</button>
      <button data-value="" value="300" class="">Fan - Furnace</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel" style="display:none;">
     <div class="row kitchen">
      <button data-value="12" value="800">Large Refridgerator</button>
      <button data-value="12" value="400">Small Refrigerator</button>
      <button data-value="12" value="350">Freezer</button>
      <button data-value="" value=""></button>
     </div>
     <div class="row kitchen">
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Oven</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="12200">Range</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Hot Plate</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1450">Microwave Oven</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1000">Microwave</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Toaster Oven</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Electric Frying Pan</button>
      <button data-value="1" value="1200">DishWasher</button>
      <button data-value="" value=""></button>
     </div>
     <div class="row kitchen">
      <button data-value="1" value="900">Coffee Maker</button>
      <button data-value="0.1" value="400">Blender/Food Processor</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="500">Blender</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Kettle</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row kitchen">
      <button data-value="0.5" value="850">Toaster</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1500">Electric Grill</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="1200">Waffle Iron</button>
      <button data-value="0.5" value="250">Rice Cooker</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="panel" style="display:none;">
     <div class="row electronics">
      <button value="" value="">Small LED TV</button>
      <button value="" value="">Large LED TV</button>
      <button value="" value="">Small LCD TV</button>
      <button value="" value="">Large LCD TV</button>
      <button value="" value="40">VCR</button>

      <button value="" value="30">CD Player</button>
      <button value="" value=""></button>
      <button value="" value=""></button>
      <button value="" class=""></button>
      <button value="" class=""></button>
     </div>
     <div class="row electronics">
      <button value="" class="50">Laptop</button>
      <button value="" class="300">Desktop Computer</button>
      <button value="" value="100">Inkjet Printer</button>
      <button value="" value="100">Lazer Printer</button>

     </div>
     <div class="row electronics">
      <button value="" value="1">Electric Clock</button>
      <button value="" value="1">Clock Radio</button>
      
      <button value="" class="100">Radiotelephone</button>
      <button value="" class="20">Stereo</button>

     </div>
     <div class="row electronics">
      <button data-value="" value="12">Shaver</button>
      <button data-value="" value="1000">Blow Dryer</button>

     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give the buttons individual ID's. It'll be much more simple. That way you can just make it so when one is clicked, hide the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var currentPanel = 1;
$('.panelControlBtn').on("click", function() {
var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
 if (ID != currentPanel) {
$(".panel").hide();
$("#panel" + ID).fadeIn('slow');
currentPanel = ID;
}
});
</script>
```

try that script

Answer (score 0):

You have three panels in page, thus $(".panel") returns 3 panel elements and fade out.
After fading out each element, fadeIn starts again.
You can detect only active panel by adding active class on switch, so that you can invoke fadeOut only on active panel.